# How to deploy a Java container using fabric-mode on a JBoss Fuse (Karaf)

Tags: osgi, esb, jbossfuse, fabric8

Is there any way to deploy a [java container](https://fabric8.io/gitbook/javaContainer.html) on a JBoss Fuse fabric?

I'm going to write some services to be deployed on JBoss Fuse 6.3, backed by Karaf, not EAP.
Fuse is deployed on-premise in fabric-mode, and uses OSGi under the hoods at least to manage the cluster infrastructure.

Fabric8 supports plain [child java containers](https://fabric8.io/gitbook/javaContainer.html#using-child-containers), but even if Fuse is based on Fabric8, probably it doesn't officially support this scenario.

For many reasons I don't want to run my services on OSGi classloaders, so I'd prefer deploying them on simple java containers, still managed by the fabric.

Is it feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Fuse 6.3 is based on Fabric8 1.2, it does not support neither Standalone-Java, Spring-Boot nor Docker containers yet, as it's based on a [specific fork](http://fabric8.io/guide/faqFuse.html) of Fabric8. It can be found here: https://github.com/jboss-fuse/fabric8

The gitbook documentation you are referring to, represents Fabric 1.2 vanilla, whereas the Fuse version also resides in this repository: https://github.com/jboss-fuse/fabric8/tree/1.2.0.redhat-6-3-x/docs. If you would like to have more proof, you can even see the adapted [modified documentation](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/fabric8/commit/76489c1a85d4666e6226f777cff768d3ef557429#diff-29f36e9e4ec4968318b3c0571b5eeeb9).

While Fuse 7.0 will bring all the Kubernetes container niceness, I also was playing with the thought on myself what I would need to `unofficially patch` Fuse in order to bring such profiles in (`fabric-process-container`), but of course it won't be supported by anyone.

Comment: Very interesting insights, especially the link to the commit that cuts down the list of supported containers... official RH docs are not so declarative. BTW if you should patch Fuse 6 to support additional containers I can contribute (on my spare time).